# How to make word concordance with Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, hit-highlighting

I would like to create a word concordance hit list with Solr, which gives **all occurrences** of the given word with context.

An English example:

```
...bla bla1 <b>dog</b> bla bla 1...
...bla bla2 <b>dog</b> bla bla 2...
...bla bla3 <b>dogs</b> bla bla 3
...bla bla4 <b>dogging</b> bla bla 4...
...bla bla5 <b>dog</b> bla bla 5...
```

It's important to be able to customize the size of the context. (Sometimes more than 1 sentence.)

**My question**: how can i do this with Solr?

Lucene 4.1 is able to do this, for example with FastVectorHighlighter:

```
    //indexing
    FieldType offsetsType = new FieldType(TextField.TYPE_STORED);
    offsetsType.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
    offsetsType.setStored(true);
    offsetsType.setIndexed(true);   
    offsetsType.setStoreTermVectors(true);
    offsetsType.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
    offsetsType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
    offsetsType.setStoreTermVectorPayloads(true);

    doc.add(new Field("content", fileContent, offsetsType));


    //searching
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    Analyzer analyzer = StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_41);
    QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_41, "content", analyzer);
    Query query = parser.parse("dog");
    TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < results.scoreDocs.length; i++) {
            int id = results.scoreDocs[i].doc;
            Document doc = searcher.doc(id);
            FastVectorHighlighter h = new FastVectorHighlighter();
            String[] hs = h.getBestFragments(h.getFieldQuery(query), reader, id, "content", contextSize, 10000);
            if (hs != null)
                    for(String f : hs)
                        System.out.println(" highlight: " + f);
    }
```

But how can i ask Solr to do the same?

My trial was this (solrconfig.xml):

```
<fragmentsBuilder name="colored" class="org.apache.solr.highlight.ScoreOrderFragmentsBuilder">
 <lst name="defaults">
 <str name="hl.tag.pre"><![CDATA[
      <b style="background:yellow">,<b style="background:lawgreen">,
      <b style="background:aquamarine">,<b style="background:magenta">,
      <b style="background:palegreen">,<b style="background:coral">,
      <b style="background:wheat">,<b style="background:khaki">,
      <b style="background:lime">,<b style="background:deepskyblue">]]></str>
 <str name="hl.tag.post"><![CDATA[</b>]]></str>
 </lst>
</fragmentsBuilder>

<requestHandler name="drupal" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
...
<str name="hl">true</str>
<str name="hl.fl">content</str>
<int name="hl.snippets">5000</int>
<int name="hl.fragsize">300</int>
<str name="hl.simple.pre"><![CDATA[ <b style="background:yellow"><i> ]]></str>
<str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[ </i></b> ]]></str>
<str name="hl.mergeContiguous">true</str>
<str name="hl.fragListBuilder">single</str>
<str name="hl.useFastVectorHighlighter">true</str>
```

But it always gives one great fragment (for each doc), but not with all occurrences.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Did you try with a smaller `hl.fragsize`, say 100?

Comment: Also I guess `<str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[ </b></i> ]]></str>` should be instead `<str name="hl.simple.post"><![CDATA[ </i></b> ]]></str>`?

Comment: I've tried hl.fragsize=100, but no changes...
Thanks for suggestion and hl.simple.post correction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with `hl.fragsize=100` and `hl.mergeContiguous=false` and see how many fragments you get?

(Before adding the params directly in your SearchHandler in solrconfig.xml you can try various options by specifying all your params in query. Once you find a set of params you are happy with, use those in solrconfig.)

Comment: hi @arun,

you pointed me to the right direction! :)

Solr **config was correct**. (when i tested solr directly, it gave every snippets happily)

**Problem was in drupal's solr module**, which i used to test results: it gave only the last snippet... :(( 



apachesolr_search.module (php code): 
`foreach ($response->highlighting->{$doc->id}->$hl_param as $values) {
            $snippets[$hl_param] = $values;
          }`

Workaround:    
          `foreach ($response->highlighting->{$doc->id}->$hl_param as $values) {
            $snippets[] = $values; //add each snippets
          }`

Answer (score 0):

I just contributed a patch http://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/LUCENE-5317 that might be of interest.  A Solr-wrapper is on its way.

Comment: This does not really constitute an answer here on SO.

Comment: It does. I don't see why it wouldn't.